# Apply and bid for an Android Development freelancing project online

Tags: marketing, group-freelancing, project-bidding

I am an Android Developer, and I'm new to freelancing. I recently created an account on sites like freelancer.com, and I want to take on some projects.

As someone new to freelancing, how can I land a project? How do I bid on freelancing sites?

Comment: for bidding we need any balance ? amount money?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I started freelancing 2 months ago with Android development and landed my first job in just 1 day. The key points are:

- you are new and probably don't have a lot of experience. So, to have a good offer that the client will take into consideration you should ask for less money that most of the people bidding. This way, even if you don't have experience people will still probably take you into consideration because of the low price, which let's face it, attracts a lot of people. Don't worry about the low prices, you only need these for your first 2-3 projects so you can get a good rating and some experience. After that you can start raising your prices and you will continue on doing this for a while.
- also make sure to state to the person that you are a beginner. Be 100% honest with that person so they know what they are getting into. So if he accepts then he is OK with your situation and is willing to take the risk of hiring you.
- make a very good written offer. That means you explain to him your situation and then start asking about his project. Ask what you do not fully understand about his requirements. Also if you have ideas that will probably be good for him propose those ideas. Even if the person might not take into consideration and apply you ideas, he will still see that you are interested in what he needs.
- if you get the project then ask a lot of questions when working on the project so you can make it exactly as the person wants it. Also propose better ways of creating something if you, as a developer, consider them better.
- also have patience. Not all people want beginners to work on their projects. So don't despair if 10 clients refused your proposal. It's enough for 1 to accept and give you work that will keep you occupied for at least 1 month.

That's pretty much it. Remember low prices and good work at first, then higher prices and better work as you gain more experience.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know specifically about freelancer.com but here's some good tips for these types of sites:

- Start with a few simple jobs to get some feedback
- Make your 'about me' type page well written and honest
- Bid for jobs with honest pricing, don't go too low and don't bid on projects that don't pay what you think is an acceptable amount for the work involved
- Communicate well and quickly with any enquiries you get
- Have a strong portfolio

Answer (score 4):

All freelancing site have a good tutorial for beginners. Read the 10 times if needed and just keep bidding. You will best learn from your own experience.

We've all been there and there is not shortcut to success.

Those who are patient will success in freelancing.